# Oracle SQL conditional grouping

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data set like this

```
Name      Service       Continuous      Start          End
A              4                 Y      04/06/2013     31/12/9999 
A              2                 N      02/02/2013     04/02/2013
B              3                 Y      05/06/2013     31/12/9999
B              2                 Y      02/06/2013     04/06/2013
B              5                 Y      27/05/2013     01/06/2013
B              4                 N      13/04/2013     17/04/2013
B              3                 Y      09/04/2013     12/04/2013
B              1                 Y      07/04/2013     08/04/2013
```

I need to add up first group of continuous periods of services for each person. Not really interested in previous periods of continuous services as the flag was set only look up the one period immediately before. So the output will be like:

```
Name        Current continuous service
A               4
B               10
```

Please for B not 14. Can anyone help me using plsql?

Comment: Your data set is missing information needed to determine the sequence of the rows - e.g. a date column.

Comment: sorry, dates can be added. I have sorted them with the first record for each name is the current service period.

Comment: Why do you need this with PL/SQL. That should be doable with plain SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a PL/SQL procedure.

A window (aka "analytical") function can be used to detect the change in the continuous flag:

```
select name, sum(service)
from (
    select *,
           case
              when lag(continuous,1,continuous) over (partition by name order by start_date desc) = continuous then 1
              else null
            end as is_valid
    from data_set
) t
where is_valid = 1
group by name;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f846b/2

Edit: I noticed that this won't get the "first" group of consecutive values only. To correctly take that restriction into account a slightly more complicated query is needed:

```
select name, sum(service)
from (
    select *,
           case
              when continuous = 'Y' or lag(continuous) over (partition by name order by start_date desc) is null then 1
              when lag(continuous,1,continuous) over (partition by name order by start_date desc) = continuous then 0
              else null
            end as marker,
            row_number() over (partition by name order by start_date desc) as rn,
            count(case when continuous = 'Y' then 1 else null end) over (partition by name order by start_date desc) as cont_count
    from data_set
) t1
where rn = cont_count 
  and marker = 1
group by name
order by name;
```

SQLFiddle for the second solution (including a "second" consecutive group for "B"):
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ca46/2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the set like:

```
 SL_NO VAL_1      VAL_2 VAL_3
     1 A              4 Y     
     2 A              2 N     
     3 B              3 Y     
     4 B              2 Y     
     5 B              5 Y     
     6 B              4 N     
     7 B              3 Y     


SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
     total NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
     FOR rec IN
     (SELECT DISTINCT val_1 FROM my_test
     )
     LOOP
          FOR rec2 IN
          (SELECT val_1, val_2, val_3
          FROM mY_test
          WHERE val_1 = rec.val_1
          ORDER BY sl_no
          )
          LOOP
               IF rec2.val_3 = 'Y' THEN
                    total   := total + rec2.val_2;
               ELSE
                    dbms_output.put_line(rec2.val_1||' '||' '||total);
               END IF;
          END LOOP;
          total := 0;
     END LOOP;
END;
```